# How to run websharper project?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

I have a websharper template project through visual studio code and ionide, I can compile the project which is great but how do I actually see the result in my web browser?

Is there anything equivalent to full visual studio's green play button?

Hope my question makes sense

Comment: I don't know WebSharper so I can't help you with specifics, but VS Code lets you define [Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) that can launch just about anything. So you could create a task for launching your web browser pointed to `http://localhost:(some-port)` and then bind that task to a keyboard shortcut. Alternately, since Ionide already defines a `Ctrl+F5` shortcut to build the default action in your FAKE `build.fsx` script, make the default action something that runs your code. See https://gist.github.com/mikesigs/72875bc7408af9202349 for inspiration.

Comment: Without knowing what the template project gave you I couldn't tell for sure, but there is usually a html file you can open that will reference the transpiled js sources. Opening that html file will show you the result, if I understand your question properly.

Comment: I'm testing out websharperspa, I can see a .html file but no associated css/js in the dir (references exist in html), I don't think pointing a webserver at this dir would work


Sounds like the task building would work but I have no idea how to start that task as a beginner to both .net and fsharp

Comment: @arcanine can you link to a github repository and I'll take a look?

Comment: https://github.com/slifin/websharper-spa-template, let me know if you need the build folder etc, looks like they're excluded from version control by default

Answer (score 1):

The result is located in the index.html file found in the WebSharperSpa directory.

Cloning the repository (https://github.com/slifin/websharper-spa-template) you have provided in your comment, I opened a bash terminal and typed the following:

```
$ chmod +x build.sh
$ ./build.sh
$ open WebSharperSpa/index.html
```

The web site displayed for me in Chrome as that is my default browser.

This is *a* way of seeing the output of your project, there may be others, but this shows the result of transpiling using WebSharper.